# Javascript href loads popup twice from second call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table where one column contains a link to it. On click of that link a pop should appear to display the data. While clicking the link first time, pop loads with data properly but from next consecutive clicks, pop loads twice attached to one another.
Code

```
<td align="center"><a class="thickbox" href="someurl" ></a></td> tried: <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="popup('url; return false;"></span></a>
```

pop loads once but doesnot display data.

tried with e.prevent default but no luck.
Also tried with return false in javascript but still no luck.
Can someone help me with any pointers on this.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Please update your question to include all relevant HTML and JavaScript. Thanks!

Comment: Post some relevant code to replicate the said issue..

Comment: the code you posted is invalid and wouldn't popup once

Comment: it may also be useful if you added the `popup` function code to the question, as that's the function you seem to be having an issue with

Comment: I've seen similar. I had loaded twice.  You need the script to check if it has already run. Something in the dom or even a cookie.

Comment: Your onclick is missing a closing single-quote "'" - is that just a typo here or is it your real code?